# Why does Hangfire wait for 15s every few seconds when polling sql server for jobs?

Tags: asp.net, .net, hangfire

I’ve inherited a system that uses Hangfire with sql server job storage. Usually when a job is scheduled to be run immediately we notice it takes a few seconds before it’s triggered.

Looking at SQL Profiler when running in my dev environment, the SQL run against Hangfire db looks like this -

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete top (1) JQ
output DELETED.Id, DELETED.JobId, DELETED.Queue
from [HangFire].JobQueue JQ with (readpast, updlock, rowlock, forceseek)
where Queue in (@queues1) and (FetchedAt is null or FetchedAt < DATEADD(second, @timeout, GETUTCDATE()))',N'@queues1 nvarchar(4000),@timeout float',@queues1=N'MYQUEUENAME_master',@timeout=-1800

-- Exactly the same SQL as above is executed about 6 times/second for about 3-4 seconds,
-- then nothing for about 2 seconds, then: 

exec sp_getapplock @Resource=N'HangFire:recurring-jobs:lock',@DbPrincipal=N'public',@LockMode=N'Exclusive',@LockOwner=N'Session',@LockTimeout=5000
exec sp_getapplock @Resource=N'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller',@DbPrincipal=N'public',@LockMode=N'Exclusive',@LockOwner=N'Session',@LockTimeout=5000
exec sp_executesql N'select top (@count) Value from [HangFire].[Set] with (readcommittedlock, forceseek) where [Key] = @key and Score between @from and @to order by Score',N'@count int,@key nvarchar(4000),@from float,@to float',@count=1000,@key=N'recurring-jobs',@from=0,@to=1596053348
exec sp_executesql N'select top (@count) Value from [HangFire].[Set] with (readcommittedlock, forceseek) where [Key] = @key and Score between @from and @to order by Score',N'@count int,@key nvarchar(4000),@from float,@to float',@count=1000,@key=N'schedule',@from=0,@to=1596053348
exec sp_releaseapplock @Resource=N'HangFire:recurring-jobs:lock',@LockOwner=N'Session'
exec sp_releaseapplock @Resource=N'HangFire:locks:schedulepoller',@LockOwner=N'Session'

-- Then nothing is executed for about 8-10 seconds, then: 

exec sp_executesql N'update [HangFire].Server set LastHeartbeat = @now where Id = @id',N'@now datetime,@id nvarchar(4000)',@now='2020-07-29 20:09:19.097',@id=N'ps12345:19764:fe362d1a-5ee4-4d97-b70d-134fdfab2b87'

-- Then about 500ms-2s later I get 
exec sp_executesql N'delete top (1) JQ ... -- i.e. Same as first query
The update LastHeartbeat query is only there every second time (from just a brief inspection, maybe that’s not exactly right).
```

It looks like there’s at least 3 threads running the DELETE query against JQ, since I can see several RPC:Starting before the RPC:Completed, suggesting they’re being executed in parallel instead of sequentially.
I don’t know if that’s normal but seems weird as I thought we had just one ‘consumer’ of the jobs.

I only have one Queue in my dev environment, although in live we’d have 20-50 I’d guess.

Any suggestions on where I should look for the configuration that’s causing:
a) the 8-10s pause between checking for jobs
b) the number of threads that are checking for jobs - it seems like I have too many

---

After writing this I realised we were using an old version so I upgraded from 1.5.x to 1.7.12, upgraded the database, and changed the startup config to this:

```
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(connstring, new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true, // Default value: true
                EnableHeavyMigrations = true     // Default value: false
            })
            .UseAutofacActivator(_container);
        JobActivator.Current = new AutofacJobActivator(_container);
```

but if anything the problem is now worse. Or the same but faster: 20 calls to `delete top (1) JQ...` happen within about 1s now, then the other queries, then a 15s wait, then it starts all over again.

To be clear, the main problem is that if any jobs are added during that 15s delay then it'll take the remainder of that 15s before my job is executed. A second problem I think is it's hitting SQL Server more than needed: 20 times in a second is a bit much, for my needs at least.

(Cross-posted to [hangfire forums](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/why-does-hangfire-pause-checking-for-jobs-from-sqlserver-for-several-seconds/7633))

Comment: According to this line in the sources, setting the QueuePollInterval to 0 makes the system switch to long polling. I suggest choosing a value strictly above 1s, say 2s, to change the wait strategy and see if it makes a difference (other than the deletes transforming to updates)
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/6fbce73f8e9058a8dcd03754092a05547e2089ba/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/SqlServerJobQueue.cs#L153

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Still doesn't explain why it'd wait 10s quite often, clearly that's bad whatever strategy it's using. But perhaps a change of strategy will mean it stops doing that anyway.

Comment: MOST IMPORTANT THING NOT TO MISS(!): There are two intervals. `QueuePollInterval` option is for fire-and-forget jobs, `SchedulePollingInterval` option is for delayed jobs. https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/polling-interval-for-fire-and-forget-background-jobs/612/5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't set `QueuePollInterval` then Hangfire with sql server storage defaults to polling every 15s. So the first thing to do if you have this problem is set `QueuePollInterval` to something smaller, e.g. 1s.

But in my case even when I set that it wasn't having any effect. The reason for that was calling `app.UseHangfireServer()` **before** I was calling `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage()` with the `SqlServerStorageOptions`.

When you call `app.UseHangfireServer()` it uses the current value of `JobStorage.Current`. My code had set that:

```
    var storage = new SqlServerStorage(connstring);
    JobStorage.Current = storage;
```

then later called

```
    app.UseHangfireServer()
```

then later called

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .UseSqlServerStorage(connstring, new SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
            PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = true, 
            EnableHeavyMigrations = true     
        })
```

Reordering it to use `SqlServerStorageOptions` before `app.UseHangfireServer()` means the `SqlServerStorageOptions` take effect.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest checking the Hangfire `BackgroundJobServerOptions` to see what polling interval you have set up there. This will define the time before the hangfire server will check to see if there are any jobs in queue to execute.

**From the documentation**

[Hangfire Docs](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html)

> Hangfire Server periodically checks the schedule to enqueue scheduled jobs to their queues, allowing workers to
> execute them. By default, check interval is equal to 15 seconds, but you can change it by setting the SchedulePollingInterval property on the options you pass to the BackgroundJobServer constructor:

```
var options = new BackgroundJobServerOptions
{
    SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
};
var server = new BackgroundJobServer(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but my `BackgroundJobServerOptions` only has the `Queues` property set. I don't quite understand what the polling interval is for, so I'll go read up on that.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. No, in this case we're usually triggering jobs to be run immediately, so the 15s polling you're talking about shouldn't be relevant, since that's for adding jobs to the queue that should be run soon, e.g. if they were created like `BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world"), TimeSpan.FromDays(1));`

Comment: You can run BackgroundJob.Schedule or BackgroundJob.Enqueue... both use the same polling interval. Do test it out and see if that helps you in your situation. Most of the values in the BackgroundJobServeroptions are set to defaults but you can override these values to something other than default (`new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)` for 5 second interval before the next job is picked up by the Hangfire server)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it all. But in general, wouldn't you expect Hangfire to poll sqlserver for new jobs continuously? I mean, why would it just stop polling? This is in the case when there are no jobs to execute ... so when we do add a job there's a big pause before it's started since Hangfire isn't continuously polling.

Comment: I awarded the bounty because your answer pointed me in the right direction, although wasn't directly solving the problem. I'll post an answer to explain more.