# Hangfire - Execution function time is not match with the scheduled job time

Tags: delay, delayed-job, hangfire, hangfire-sql

We have scheduled TriggerdNotitication() function at **12.10.10PM**

**Expected** would be TriggerdNotitication() will be executed at **12.10.10PM**
**But Actual** TriggerdNotitication() is executed at **12.10.25PM**

**Version:** 1.8.2

why this taken extra 15 sec sometimes its increase to 20sec sometimes its 14 sec it is not exact match with scheduled time

we have found this major issue as notification is delay instead within 1min it sent around 45sec or 40 sec

```
  TimeZoneInfo siteTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(SiteClient.SiteTimeZone);
    scheduleTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(scheduleTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, siteTZ);
     scheduleTime = scheduleTime.AddHours(HelperMethods.GetHangireAWTimeZoneOffset());

     //Removing ACP-> PerItemItem from scheduled time
      scheduleTime = scheduleTime.AddMinutes(-Convert.ToDouble(perItemTiggerTime));

      BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => TriggerdNotitication(eventID, triggerTime), scheduleTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution reduced the default queueing time 15 seconds to 5seconds

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_connection"].ConnectionString,
    new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions
    { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) });

app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
{
    SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Schedule settings in Hangfire is not for job execution - rather for job enqueue.
That means that job will be placed in queue and executed when one of the workers on hangfire server is available.

There can be delay if:

1. something else is executing - or server has some unexpected load.
2. hangfire reads job definition from database, and persists new state every time so if you database is loaded at the moment - delay can happen.

Comment: Also, there is the QueuePollInterval, which can delay execution a bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291101/79485