# Hangfire cron job does not execute at a specific time

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1, hangfire

I have a cron job using Hangfire in an ASP.NET Core Web API. From my dashboard, I can see that the next job execution time is correct, but in real life, it runs after that time.

Here is my code snap

[stratup.cs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhVpe.png)

I tried with cron expression but that did not work

Comment: Are you sure the Local time zone is the correct one? The Local time zone means the timezone of the server in which the application is running. you can give it a try to change the timezone into a more strict one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hangfire - Execution function time is not match with the scheduled job time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001161/hangfire-execution-function-time-is-not-match-with-the-scheduled-job-time)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the storage? SQL Server?